# React Virtualized windowscroller scrollElement not working

Tags: react-virtualized

You were right that I was not passing the props in correctly. Now I have it set up as such:

Container.jsx

```
<div className='container' ref={(ref) => {this.foo = ref;}}>
  this.renderContainer()
</div>

<Section scrollContainer={this.foo}/>
```

Section.jsx (just passing down props)

```
<Panel scrollContainer={this.props.scrollContainer}/>

Section.propTypes = { scrollContainer: PropTypes.object.isRequired }
```

Panel.jsx (Passing down props)

```
<RenderedTable scrollContainer={this.props.scrollContainer} />
```

RenderedTable.jsx

```
return (
  <div className='padding-top-20 font-smoothing'>
    <WindowScroller scrollElement={this.props.scrollContainer}>
      {({ height, isScrolling, scrollTop, onChildScroll }) => (
        <AutoSizer disableHeight>
          {({ width }) => (
            <Table
```

Unfortunately the windowScroller still does not resize. I also dont get any warnings or errors. Do you use css tricks to get the scroller to resize? I see that in the example https://bvaughn.github.io/react-virtualized/#/components/WindowScroller
you change the flex and overflow properties when changing the scrollElement from window to scrollingBody.

I know you are very busy and greatly appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0):

In your example, you've assigned the scroll ref to `this.tabsContainer` but you're trying to access it as `this.props.tabContainer`. Either this is your mistake, or the example is incomplete and more context is needed. :) Can you provide a Plnkr?